# Db2: Changes to setting of SQL_COMPAT global variable are not reflected

Tags: db2, netezza

When we change the SQL_COMPAT global variable to NPS, the result is not reflected. Why, what can we do?

The method we tried was

```
SET SQL_COMPAT = 'NPS'
```

After this, `VALUES SQL_COMPAT` was executed, but it remained NULL.
We obtained instructions from this URL: 
https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/ja/SS6NHC/com.ibm.swg.im.dashdb.sql.ref.doc/doc/globvar_sql_compat.html"

Answer (score 1):

The global variable [SQL_COMPAT](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SS6NHC/com.ibm.swg.im.dashdb.sql.ref.doc/doc/globvar_sql_compat.html) was [introduced in Db2 Version 11.1](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_11.1.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.wn.doc/doc/c0054107.html). You need to be on that level or higher. It is a session variable, so the change is only visible within the same session.

If you are connected to Db2, if you set SQL_COMPAT using

```
SET SQL_COMPAT='NPS'
```

and in the same (connected) session you execute

```
VALUES SQL_COMPAT
```

it should be visible.